# Prove that $|x|^{s-1}x$ is not differentiable at 0.

Tags: analysis, derivatives

> Let $F_s : \mathbb{B}^n \to \mathbb{B}^n$ be given by $F_s (x) = |x|^{s-1}x$ for $s>0$. Prove that $F_s$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

I have been attempting this for the last 40 minutes and it seems so simple but it has been ruining me. My attempt:

Write $F_s$ as its component functions 
$\begin{pmatrix} |x|^{s-1}\pi^1(x)\\ |x|^{s-1}\pi^2(x) \\ \vdots \\|x|^{s-1}\pi^n(x) \end{pmatrix}.$

Then if $F_s$ is differentiable at $0$, each of it's component functions must be, and we can write it in terms of the partials as a 1xn matrix, so $D(|x|^{s-1}\pi^k(x)) = \big(0, \ldots, D_k|x|^{s-1}\pi^k(x), \ldots, 0 \big).$

But calculating the kth partial is giving me hell:
$$D_k f^k(0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f^k(te_k) - f^k(0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{|te_k|^{s-1}t - 0}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} |t|^{s-1} = 0$$

for $s>1$.

Should the partial not exist??? What's going on...

Comment: Consider $s=\frac12$

Comment: @Minz I wrote $s > 1$. For $s < 1$ it is obvious that the last limit does not exist.

Comment: @ Airdish From differentianity follows the existance of partial derivatives but but not vice versa

Comment: What is $F_s(0)$? What is $\mathbb B^{n}$?. You wrote $s>0$ in the first line but I thin k you want to take $s>1$ and define $F_s(0)$ as $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Differentianity means that $F(x)-F(x_0)=A(x-x_0)+o(|x-x_0|)$ for some matrix $A$

If $F$ has this property then it has partial deriveties and they consist matrix $A$. You have shown that $F$ has (and the matrix is zero) but it is not sufficient for differentianity.

From the definition should be $0=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)}{|x|}=
\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{|x|^{s-1}x}{|x|} $

Can you finish depending on the value of $s$?